# Call callback stored as member variable

Tags: php, callback

Is it possible with php to directly call a callback stored in an member variable of a class? currently I'm using a workaround, where I'm temporarily storing my callback to a local var.

```
class CB {
  private $cb;
  public function __construct($cb) {
    $this->cb = $cb;
  }
  public function call() {
    $this->cb(); // does not work
    $cb = $this->cb;
    $cb(); // does work
  }
}
```

php complains that `$this->cb()` is not a valid method, i.e. does not exist.

Comment: Similar question asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656151/php-callable-object-as-object-member). Cliff notes version: "Mostly because of the loose typing. There's no way of actually infering what you might mean to do, so it defaults to erroring early."

Comment: Perhaps `{$this->cb}()`? The `{}` should force PHP to see the cb reference as the `$cb` member var, and not as a cb method in the object.

Comment: marc, no, »unexpected {, expecting _something else_ …«

Comment: Do you have a sample use case?

Comment: @FooBah: allowing users of the class to provide a log function (see the question [PHP Callable Object as Object Member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656151/php-callable-object-as-object-member))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `call_user_func`:

```
class CB {
    private $cb;
    public function __construct($cb) {
        $this->cb = $cb;
    }
    public function call() {
        call_user_func($this->cb, 'hi');
    }
}

$cb = new CB(function($param) { echo $param; });
$cb->call(); // echoes 'hi'
```

Comment: A pity I cannot call it directly, but I guess there's no way around using either `call_user_func` or storing the callback in a local var. Seems like the PHP parser is quite limited in some regards. `call_user_func` is as good as it gets, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In php7 you can call it like this:

```
class CB {
  /** @var callable */
  private $cb;
  public function __construct(callable $cb) {
    $this->cb = $cb;
  }
  public function call() {
    ($this->cb)();
  }
}
```