# Pass Method form different class for later execution to a second class

Tags: php

I have to classes and I want to pass a method fro classA to classB constructor and store it on a classB instance variable so as to execute it later.

```
    class A
    { 
        public function execute()
        {
            $ClassB = new ElgEmpAnalyticsImporterControllerImporterEmporioOrder(ConMW::getDB(), $this -> lPointFile, [$this, 'getLastPoints'] );
            $ClassB -> import();   
        }

        public function getLastPoints(Array $keys)
        {
            $res = [];
            forEach ( json_decode( file_get_contents($this -> lastPointFile) ) as $key => $value ):
                if ( in_array($key, $keys) ):
                    $res[$key] = $value;
                else:
                    $res[$key] = '';
                endif;
            endforeach;
            unset($key);
            unset($value);
            return $res;
        }

    }


    classB
    { 
        public $getLastPoints = null;

        public function __construct(callable $getLastPoints) 
        {
            $this -> getLastPoints =  $getLastPoints;
        }

        public function import()
        {
            $lastPoints = $this -> getLastPoints(['idOrder', 'orderLastExport']);              
        }
    }
```

Trying to execute it like that I get the error "Call to undefined method getLastPoints()"

I think the problem is on storing the function on the instance variable $getLastPoints of classB. I can conclude this because If I execute the function on the constructor it works. That means if I change the constructor of classB like this

```
    classB
    { 
        public $getLastPoints = null;

        public function __construct(callable $getLastPoints) 
        {
            $getLastPoints(['idOrder', 'orderLastExport']);
        }


    }
```

it  works.

But what i need is to execute the external function inside the import function.

Can someone please help me?

thanks for your time,

Edit for clarification: My question is why I can execute the function inside the contructor like this :

```
$lastPoint(a,b)
```

but when I assign the callable into an instance variable like this:

```
$this -> lastPoint(a,b)
```

it does not work.

I read that php uses different storage for variables and function. PHP probably sees the callable $lastPoints as a variable. So can the callable $lastPoints, be added as dynamic function to my instance of classB?

Christoforos

Comment: Is this for real `ElgEmpAnalyticsImporterControllerImporterEmporioOrder`?

Comment: Just store the value of the method getLastPoints()  inside a variable into the class A, then pass that variable when creating a new B object

Comment: Sorry AbraCadaver  ElgEmpAnalyticsImporterControllerImporterEmporioOrder is ClassB

Comment: Just a very short question: Why?

Comment: Damian Dominella: I need to be able to run the function at runtime. The above is an sample. This function is called several times in the real program, and I its return value is not the same.

Comment: k0pernikus: as I comment to Damian the above is a sample. This function is called several times in the ClassB so I need reference to It, so as it can be executed. ClassA also uses some other classes except classB. These other classes also using this function several times. So I need to be able to pass this function from classA  to ClassB, classC etc, and those classes must be able to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Callable Object as Object Member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656151/php-callable-object-as-object-member)

$getlastpoints is a property with an array value stored in it, not a function.
call_user_func_array($this->getlastpoints, ['idOrder', 'orderLastExport']);

```
public function import()
    {
        $my_func = $this->getLastPoints;
        $lastPoints = $my_func(['idOrder', 'orderLastExport']);              
    }
```

In a nutshell, the reason you will have to do this is because you can define properties and methods in a PHP class having the same name.  e.g.

```
class foo {
  public $bar
  public function bar() {}
}
```

so in this instance, if allowed to directly access a stored callable on the $bar property... What would the call below reference?

```
$my_foo_obj->bar()
```

To avoid the situation, you cannot call it directly.

Comment: Sorry I get error "getLastPoints() must be of the type array, string given." Any way my question why I can not call the function through another functoin like $this -> getLastPoint(a,b) while I can do it inside the construct like this: $lastPoint(a, b).

Comment: Because you have a reference to the callable which you are using in the constructor.  What version of PHP are you using, because the answer will differ between 5 and 7.  But basically, in older versions, you want to store an array with the object and method and use the call_user_func.  You can also use the invoke method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380745/is-is-possible-to-store-a-reference-to-an-object-method

Comment: I am using PHP 7. So the problem is to find a way to use the callable outside the constructor? I am assign the variable $getInstancePoint, which is of type calable, to an instance variable on classB. Shouldn't this instance variable be of the type callable also and be executed directly also?

Comment: Expanded my answer to address the question in your comment.  As for the variable assignment and then using that as the function, you may still need to store a reference to the object and use $myobj->$myfunc as I'm uncertain whether assigning the callable to your property is going to maintain the object reference, or just assign a lambda function.  You'll have to do some testing to answer that one.